# How do I use phpcs in sublime to learn coding standards?

Tags: php, coding-style, workflow, sublimetext2

I want to learn to code PHP to standard. I found [this](http://www.neverstopbuilding.com/sublime-plugins-for-php) article and (on its advice) installed phpcs in sublime text 2. If I go to tools -->phpcode sniffer -->sniff this file it will find syntax errors but not coding standard deviations. (Here is the code I am trying to sniff, which I think has many deviations from standard https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/57045/simple-wrapper-for-an-api).

The [docs say to configure phpcs to use a coding standard](http://benmatselby.github.io/sublime-phpcs/#configuration) via `phpcs_additional_args`. If I go to sublimetext2->preferences->package settings->phpcode sniffer->settings user I see the following code:

```
   "phpcs_additional_args": {
        "--standard": "PSR2",
        "-n": ""
    },
```

Here is my [full config file](https://gist.github.com/AbeHandler/103c33f728237689071c).

Do I have the workflow right? If so, why isn't it finding my mistakes? How do I use phpcs to teach myself coding standards? Even knowing that I am doing the correct steps but the plugin is not outputting the coding standard marks would be helpful.

Answer (score 9):

Based on your configuration file, there are some things you must fix:

**Following instructions are for linux (ubuntu), or mac**

1. Ensure you have installed [PEAR](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.getting.php)
2. Install php code sniffer

   `pear install PHP_CodeSniffer`

   reload your bash or zsh and then execute command, if you don't know how to do this, just restart your terminal app

   `which phpcs`

   copy the output and paste to `"phpcs_executable_path":` at phpcs config

   currently, you're pointing `"phpcs_executable_path":` to php, not phpcs, so thats why its doesn't work
3. Install php mess detector

   `pear channel-discover pear.phpmd.org
   pear channel-discover pear.pdepend.org
   pear install pdepend/PHP_Depend
   pear install --alldeps phpmd/PHP_PMD`

   do like phpcs above

   reload enviroment and execute `which phpmd`, then fill `"phpmd_executable_path": ""` at phpcs config
4. install php-cs-fixer

   `sudo wget http://get.sensiolabs.org/php-cs-fixer.phar -O /usr/local/bin/php-cs-fixer
   sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/php-cs-fixer`

   change `"php_cs_fixer_executable_path": ""` to `"php_cs_fixer_executable_path": "/usr/local/bin/php-cs-fixer"`
5. install scheck

   `cd /opt/
   git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/facebook/pfff.git
   cd pfff/ 
   ./configure
   make depend
   make
   make opt`

   change `"scheck_executable_path"` to  `"scheck_executable_path": "/opt/pfff/scheck"`

Note: you may use `sudo pear ...` instead `pear ...`

Answer (score 1):

I use it with phpstorm because it near enough works out of the box, however I think this might be were you find your answer: https://github.com/benmatselby/sublime-phpcs

Comment: **Note:** *sublime-phpcs* has been abandoned by its author. No guarantee it will work in the future.

Answer (score -1):

after saving your .php file right click and go Php Code Sniffer and you will see variants.

[image]